# How to run nginx with docker container?

Tags: bash, docker

I tried to install nginx within my docker container, before the installation i want to run

the `docker run -i -t base /bin/bash` command and  but i got a error like this..

> WARNING: Local (127.0.0.1) DNS resolver found in resolv.conf and
>   containers can't use it.
>
> Using default external servers : [8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4]
>
> [error] client.go:2298 Error getting size: bad file descriptor

How can i solve this?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with nginx. I got the exact same error when following http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-raring-saucy

Comment: The problem seems to be with the tty somehow, It seems this line is causing the error: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/api/client.go#L2308

Comment: Related issue on docker repo: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4568

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For me, this fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get install cgroup-lite
```

However, it seems to be a bunch of related problems. For other solutions/work-arounds, see: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4568